# How to Save JRadioButton or JCheckbox data into File

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, javax

I have a JFrame inside it has JButton and JCheckBox
The only problem is that there is submit button , i double click on it to write code,
but how to get JcheckBox or JRadioButton Data store to File . and then how to read it From file??

I write JCheckBox.getText(); and similarly for JRadioButton
even used InputOutputStream , PrintWriter .
tried to store them in int , and then in string but still not working

Anyway to store JCheckBox and JRadioButton into file and then after that how to read them too.
using Netbeans.

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: Its just simple JRadioButton and JCheckBox in a Frame. i write the code , but it was not working so i clear all the code

Comment: @explv I just need code to put data of JRadioButton and JCheckBox to file and to read that data .. i write the code with FileOutputStream and PrintWriter but i clear it , as it was not working

Comment: @Bentaye  help???

Answer (score -1):

Simple i Found the solution by my self

```
if(JRadioButton1.isSelected()){
                String temp = "true";
                  fw.write("Outside Volunteer = " + temp);
```

}